# Passing values from cshtml to a component

Tags: angular

I am using MVC structure , I have an cstmh page where I pass spme values to my home component . I get undefined and not sure why

cshtml

```
<home [gwLinkID]="11111"></home>
    <ng-component></ng-component>
```

also tried

```
<home gwLinkID="11111"></home>
<ng-component></ng-component>
```

home.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './navmenu/navMenu.component';


    @Input() gwLinkID: number;

    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
        this.gwLinkID = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('gwLinkID'); also tried


    }
```

what am i Missing

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({

    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'


})
export class AppComponent {



}
```

app.module

```
@NgModule({

    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }

        ]),


        CommonModule, NavMenuModule, TabModule, SharedModule


    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, WelcomeComponent],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Try removing square brackets `gwLinkID="11111"`

Comment: already did, and it did not work

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/e1OaJhEsW8ioFQ6zE4CL?p=preview

Comment: Why do you have `<ng-component></ng-component>`? Which is your root component?

Comment: it is for the routing, I used to have it like the plunker that you created and everything worked fine, however, when I did routing had to make these changes otherwise, home component used to get initialized twice

Comment: also edited my above code